# How to use "std_logic" after package/package body declaration?

Tags: package, vhdl, ieee, ghdl

I am trying to get better with VHDL, therefore i wanted to try to implement the functions "package ... is" and "package body ... is". 
When i do this it seems like "std_logic" can't see the contents of the IEEEE library in the step of the GHDL Analysis.

So far i tried the commands with and without code in them -> Same result. 
Without the "package"-lines it works like a charme...but i won't be able to extend it like planned.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

package run is
    -- some package definitions
end run;

package body run is
    -- the body
end run;

entity andfunc is
    Port( A : in std_logic;
        B : in std_logic;
        C : out std_logic
);
end andfunc;

architecture Behavioral of andfunc is
begin
    C <= A and B ;
end Behavioral;
```

The specific Error Message is: 
"[...] error: no declaration for "std_logic"

Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope (the visibility) of `library` and `use` is not the entire file. After a `package` you have to recall them if you still need them. In order to work your code should be:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

package run is
    -- some package definitions
end run;

package body run is
    -- the body
end run;


library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity andfunc is
    Port( A : in std_logic;
        B : in std_logic;
        C : out std_logic
);
end andfunc;

architecture Behavioral of andfunc is
begin
    C <= A and B ;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your std_logic_1164 import belongs to the package and is also visible in its body. It's not visible in the entire file. Repeat those lines before the entity and it will be visible for the entity and its architecture.

Comment: Thank you very much. *Face to table*. Works now +1